# Python port scanner marks every port as closed when using for loop and range function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to make a simple Python port scanner script, connect to IP and port/s, if connection is successful, the port should be marked as open.

I have tried to omit the for loop and the range function, using the port number explicitly and it works, but for some reason it does not like the iteration thing, also tried to use connect_ex function and did not work.

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1200))
s.listen(600)

print("Waiting for connections...")
while 1:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!","utf-8"))
```

portScanner.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

for port in range(1000,1400):
    try:
        s.settimeout(3)
        connection = s.connect(("127.0.0.1",port))
        print(f"Port {port} is open!")
    except:
        print(f"Port {port} is closed.")

s.close()
```

I expect the output to be "Port 1200 is open!" among the lines of Port xxxx is closed., but the actual output is all the ports are marked as closed.

Comment: I get `"Port 1200 is open!"` on Linux Mint

Comment: maybe you should always use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see what is the problem.

Comment: @furas Thank you for the tip, I will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in the fact that you're trying to use the same socket for each connection.  I'm able to reproduce your issue on a mac, though the issue might be platform dependent as the socket library calls the OS directly.

In your code the first exception thrown is `[Errno 61] Connection refused` and then everything after is `[Errno 22] Invalid argument`, so there is something in the state of the socket that is causing all other connection attempts to fail.  Note that you're not calling `s.close()` in a finally block in the loop which you should be doing, but even doing that will give you a `[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` error.

In any event, I was able to get this to work by creating a new socket for each connect attempt and properly closing it with a `with` block:

```
for port in range(1000, 1400):
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.settimeout(3)
            connection = s.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))
            print(f"Port {port} is open!")
    except:
        print(f"Port {port} is closed.")
```

Comment: Perfectly right. A TCP socket cannot be used for multiple connections or connection attempts.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly, I learned something new today, much appreciated!