# Should I create a new instance for every single port?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, port-scanning

I am making a port scanner using the python socket library which basically tries to connect to an IP on a port. If it is able to connect, then the port is shown open, otherwise, it displays the port as closed.

Note that this is just a basic port scanner and I am still working on it.

So, I was thinking, why don't I initiate the socket instance outside the for loop as my code is creating a new instance every time

But, when I tried it, it was saying that every port was closed

This is the snippet that I am using before the for loop -

```
socket_instance = socket.socket()  
socket_instance.settimeout(0.5)
```

(I don't know about socket programming in python)
Here is the main section of the code that is working properly -

```
def scan_ports(ip_address,port):
      try:
        socket_instance.connect((ip_address, port))
        print("[+] Port "+str(port)+" is open")
        socket_instance.close()
      except:
        # print("[-] Port "+str(port)+" closed") 
        pass

for port in range(1,501):
    socket_instance = socket.socket()  
    socket_instance.settimeout(0.5) 
    scan_ports(ip_address,port)
```

So my question is: do I have to create a new instance of the socket function for every port?

Can't I just reuse the same instance for every port?

Comment: You can't reuse sockets at all. It was *your code* that said every port was closed, but that was a conclusion that you jumped to because you ignored the actual error message.

Comment: My bad, I should have removed the try...except block. 
I would have actually gotten an error then.

Comment: And I guess this question has already been answered in this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132550/python-port-scanner-marks-every-port-as-closed-when-using-for-loop-and-range-fun?rq=2